# How to snap-to-grid CGPoint in macOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift2

How can I snap a CGPoint to grid (as found in AutoCAD) pressing a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: you mean in the interface builder or the final product where you move objects?

Comment: Sorry, I mean in final product.

Comment: please post a code snippet so I can post the most appropriate version for you.

Comment: i have answered the question with pseudo code, when you paste your code, i can edit my answer to reflect into your problem, but at least the answer has a pseudo code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the general way to do it, something like a pseudo code

```
var gridWidth = 16.0
var gridHeight = 16.0

object.Position.X = Math.Floor(object.Position.X / gridWidth) * gridWidth
object.Position.Y = Math.Floor(object.Position.Y / gridHeight) * gridHeight
```